# Unable to get 30fps @ 1080P with logitech C930

Tags: webcam, logitech-webcam

Have double checked the webcam specs here
https://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/webcam-c930e-business/specs

which confirm I SHOULD be able to get full HD at 30fps.

I have also installed the latest drivers and firmware.

I am on Windows 10.

If I set the requested resolution to 720P (1280x720) I can achieve close to 30fps.

However when i request the camera's maximum resolution (1920x1080) I can only get maybe 10fps video playback.

Very frustrating!

Comment: Are you sure the issue is with the camera? This camera offloads most of its processing to the computer, and so there's a good change the problem is that your computer cannot handle that load. Please add your computer's specs to your question.